# RTF-document doesn't display PNG-image

Tags: .net, windows, png, rtf, wordpad

I have next problem: 
after insert (in .Net, WPF) PNG-image into RTF-document and save it to disk I tried open saved RTF-document through WordPad (I have windows 8), but saved **PNG-file DOESN'T Displaying** in **RTF-document** in **WordPad** in **windows 8**. But, in **windows 7** - successfully image shows.

So I can't understand where is problem(?)...
May be problem in version's compatibility of "**viewer in rtf**" (**RichView version**) or something else? I tried open RTF-document in binary format and find tags about versions of RichViewer, and other but can't find anything.

May be anybody know what can be there...?

**Rtf-file with picture:**

{\ltrch {*\shppict{\pict\picwgoal2685\pichgoal945\pngblip
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}}}

Comment: How are you inserting the picture.  Are you hand-rolling the RTF?  Are you inserting into a RichTextBox or something else?

Comment: I insert Picture to tag **<Paragraph>**, then paragraph insert into the Table and table insert to blocks "Section.block.Add(...)" and save RTF-document like **FlowDocument**.

Comment: I had to do this in one of the programs I'm writing.  In a `RichTextBox`, I'm making a `BitmapImage` from a `URI` and filename.  Then I'm making an `Image` with `FormatConvertedBitmap`, then adding that to a `InlineUIContainer` and then finally adding that to the paragraph with `RichTextBox.Selection.Start.Paragraph.Inlines.Add`.

I'm not sure why you're bringing tables into this, try doing it without the tables.  This way you get more control over the placement by using an `InlineUIContainer`.

Comment: I use **Table** for for correct position of Picture in my document.

Comment: May be try Save RTF-file by another way? Now I'm saving text to rtf by **FileStream**.

Comment: You could probably achieve the same positioning with an `InlineUIContainer` or even a `BlockUIContainer`.  I'm just trying to weed out what the problem might be.  If you're adding an image to a table and not setting any of the table properties, maybe something changed in Windows 8 that I'm not aware of that might be causing you problems.

To save I'm using `new TextRange(richTextBox.Document.ContentStart, richTextBox.Document.ContentEnd).Save(fileStream, DataFormats.Rtf)`

Comment: Yeah, I'm saving RTF file similarly like you. But may be you know how save RTF file by another way?

Comment: I tried find something about saving through COM, but can't find anything.

Comment: Not that I can think of.  My only suggestion is to try it without the table.  Try to just get the picture to show up any way that you can, then add extra functionality like putting it in a table or something like that.

Comment: Okay, over 10 minutes I'll try...just a moment.

Comment: Well...I saved without Table, saved just Paragraph. But result is similarly - in WordPad I can't see my saved picture.

Comment: Something must have changed in Windows 8, I don't know what else to say because I can't reproduce your problem, sorry :/

Comment: I found library Spire.Doc - it can save, convert different documents. But it cost 799$. Maybe you know similarly library for work with documents?

Comment: ToastyMallows, Thanks :)